# How to execute PERL scripts in Django using async tasker like Celery?

Tags: python, django, perl, rabbitmq, celery

I have a need to execute PERL scripts through a Django web interface.

The user will select the parameters of the script and execute it.

I am wondering if it is possible to use Celery/RabbitMQ to execute these script as Celery tasks?

If so, would I need to modify the PERL script? 
Would I have to write RabbitMQ code into the PERL scripts? Or would I just execute the Celery task and wait for the script to finish processing? I would like to have the script update the Django user/celery.

Comment: The proper casing is Perl, when you are talking about the language, or perl when you are talking about the executable. ( It is **NOT** an acronym )

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to execute a Perl script from Celery would probably be a thin wrapper written in Python that runs the script as a subprocess.

Comment: This sounds logical I was complicating it to much. Appreciate your response I will give it a go and mark it correct if I get that to work.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Minion](https://github.com/kraih/minion), the Perl job queue from Mojoliciuous (Perl Web Framework)

> A job queue for the Mojolicious real-time web framework, with support
>   for multiple named queues, priorities, delayed jobs, job results,
>   retries with backoff, statistics, distributed workers, parallel
>   processing, autoscaling, resource leak protection and multiple
>   backends (such as PostgreSQL).